# Iterating through two arrays, having trouble with indices

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question about creating dynamic arrays and iterating through these arrays. I have a method setVoltage that takes as parameters a string and a double value. I needed some way to store these values so I created two arrays. What i need to do is iterate through the String array to see if the string parameter already exists and if it does, to set the corresponding voltage at that index. If it doesn't exist, i need to add the string device to the string array and also add the double voltage to the double array. Can someone check out my code and see what I am missing? I'm running into trouble because I want the array to realize the string is already in the array, or append it to the end of the array but I'm stuck on how to use index variables to achieve this. Thank you!

```
    public final int sizeArray = 10;
private String[] deviceList = new String[sizeArray]; 
public double[] voltList = new double[sizeArray];

public synchronized void setVoltage(String device, double voltage) {

        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < deviceList.length; i++ ){
            //if the device name already exists in the device array, overwrite voltage at that index 
            if(this.deviceList[i].equals(device)){
            index = i;
            voltList[index] = voltage;
            }else{
            //set deviceList[i] equal to device, set voltList[i] equal to voltage
            deviceList[i] = device;
            voltList[i] = voltage;
            index++;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like perhaps you want a `Map<String,Double>` instead. This will let you store voltage values keyed by device name, and you can easily find, insert, and remove devices. See, for example, [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
Map<String,Double> deviceVoltages = new HashMap<String,Double>(); 
deviceVoltages.put("liquifier", 8.4);
deviceVoltages.put("reflarbulator", 900.0);
deviceVoltages.put("liquifier", 13.3); // replaces previous 8.4
System.out.println(deviceVoltages.get("liquifier")); 
deviceVoltages.remove("reflarbulator");
```

Your example code then reduces to simply:

```
private Map<String,Double> deviceVoltages = new HashMap<String,Double>(); 

public synchronized void setVoltage(String device, double voltage) {
    deviceVoltages.put(device, voltage);
}
```

Performance will exceed that of your array, and you will not have a hard-coded limit on number of devices.

See generic [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) documentation for links to other types of maps in the JDK.

See also [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) if a finer synchronization granularity is desired and/or acceptable.

An alternative, if you must use arrays, is to create a `Device` class that encapsulates all the relevant information about a device and use a single array to simplify your logic, e.g.:

```
static class Device {
    String name; 
    double voltage;
}

Device[] devices = new Device[10];
```

You can add new devices by replacing a `null` element in the array. You can update devices by finding the one with the specified name and changing its `voltage` field. You can optionally use a `List<Device>` to avoid hard-coded size limits.

Answer (score 0):

It would be way better to use a `Map<String,Double>` in this scenario. But if you still want to use two arrays, your current code is not appending to the end of the array. Say if `i=0` and `deviceList[i] != device` , then your code immediately overwrites `deviceList[i]` with the new value in the `else` block rather than appending it to the end of the array. To append, you have to move the code in the else part to after the `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always overwrite the device if the device name was not found.  It would be better if you used a Map but if you are required to use arrays you can try the following

```
   for(int i = 0; i < deviceList.length; i++ ){
        //if the device name already exists in the device array, overwrite voltage at that index 
        if(this.deviceList[i].equals(device)){
          voltList[i] = voltage;
          break;
        }else if (deviceList[i] == null) {
          //set deviceList[i] equal to device, set voltList[i] equal to voltage
          deviceList[i] = device;
          voltList[i] = voltage;
          break;
        }
    }
```

You'll have to write some additional code to deal with a full array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it as-is:

```
public void setOrAppend(String device, double voltage) {

    int index = 0;
    for ( ; index < deviceList.length; i++) {
        if (device.equals(deviceList[index]) || deviceList[index] == null) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index == deviceList.length) {
        deviceList = Arrays.copyOf(deviceList, deviceList.length + 1);
        voltList = Arrays.copyOf(voltList, voltList.length + 1);
    }

    deviceList[index] = device;
    voltList[index] = voltage;
}
```

I would recommend doing the set logic outside the loop. Additionally I would also recommend a Map for this kind of scenario since this kind of logic is simpler. A Map will already do what you are asking automatically (replace if exists otherwise append).

Comment: One thing to be careful of is that if any other code is maintaining a reference to `deviceList` or `voltList` (perhaps directly, perhaps via `Arrays.asList()`), this will not modify those referenced arrays if a new element is added. That may be acceptable (and the OP did not mark them as `final`). Using a mutable container e.g. a `List` is one option to avoid that.

Comment: @JasonC There's no way to resize an array that doesn't discard the original one.